# getting specific value using awk command in linux

Tags: awk

I have a following file.

```
cat test.txt
NE|East
OR|East
WB|East
HP|North
HR|North
JK|North
NR|North
PB|North
```

I have a variable circle which stores the following value.
`circle="JK"`

Now, I want the value matching my variable. I have used the following code, but it doesn't provide me any output. However, when I manually writes "JK", it shows me the desired result.

`awk -F '|' '{if($1==$circle) print $2;}' test.txt`

`awk -F '|' '{if($1 == "JK") print $2;}' test.txt
North`

Please suggest. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
val="$JK"
awk -v var="$val"  -F'|' '$1==var{print $2}' Input_file
```

Comment: It worked ! But I only want $2 to be printed .. and when I use `awk -v var="$circle" -F '|' '$1==var' '{print $2;}' test.txt` it shows me error

Comment: @naggarwal11, please check now and let me know then.

Comment: Perfect ! thanks :)